# Node js Socket.io : How to avoid multiple user connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm working on a node.js + socket.io project and I wanted to know how I could prevent my users to identify themselves several times with the same login.

In fact, I want to disconnect a user who is already connected  if this user attempts to sign in with the same account.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: You shouldn't do this.  Sometimes users get disconnected and reconnect on a completely new connection before the old one dies off.

Answer (score 1):

When a user connected, force him/ her to fulfill some authentication, so each of your `socket` connection has an identifier. With that identifier, you can search is there any user logged in with same identity? If yes, force to disconnect.